# What does $\langle\nabla f(s),q-p\rangle$ mean?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I saw this notation used in a problem and wasn't able to understand what it means. It appears in the context of the Lagrange theorem for multi-variable functions.

$q,p,s$ are all points.

Comment: Probably it is the notation for an inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that $f: \mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is a function with enough regularity and that $\nabla f$ is its gradient.

The notation $\langle v,w\rangle $ is fairly standard for the scalar product of the vectors $v$ and $w$. In this case, note that $\nabla f(s)$ is the gradient of $f$ at $s$ and is a vector pointing towards the direction in which $f$ grows the most. $q-p$ is a vector, since $q$ and $p$ are points.

So $\langle \nabla f(s),q-p\rangle $ will be a real number. The standard scalar product, which is the one used nearly in every single problem is calculated as follows: if $v = (v_1,\dots, v_n)$ and $w=(w_1,\dots,w_n)$, then $\langle v,w\rangle  = \sum_{k=1}^n v_k\cdot w_k$.

Comment: Inner product (see Bernard's comment) is just another name for scalar product. The name I use is no better than his, and examples of either abound in the literature.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Bernard, for the comment. To be fair, LaTeX is one of my areas for improvement :/

Answer (score 0):

In $\langle\nabla f(s),q-p\rangle$, as a comment states, the $\langle$ and $\rangle$ point to an inner product between the function $\nabla f(s)$ and $q-p$ while $\nabla f(s) $ equals the vector $\left(\frac{\partial f(s)}{\partial s_1},...,\frac{\partial f(s)}{\partial s_N} \right)^T $ if $s$ is an $N$-dimensional vector.